# Select sum from

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am trying to get the sum of all the rows associated with each customer and join on them.

However I am finding that if no rows exist it leaves out the customer completely.

I would prefer if the sum was zero. How would I achieve this.

Here is the SQL statement:

```
SELECT 
    Id, DebitSum
FROM
    Customers
JOIN
    (SELECT 
         SUM(Amount) DebitSum, CustomerId
     FROM 
         Purchases
     WHERE 
         Completed IS NULL
     GROUP BY 
         CustomerId) p ON p.CustomerId = Id;
```

Using SQL Server, if it matters.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just use `LEFT JOIN`:

```
SELECT c.Id, COALESCE(p.DebitSum, 0)
FROM Customers c LEFT JOIN
     (SELECT SUM(p.Amount) as DebitSum, p.CustomerId
      FROM Purchases p
      WHERE p.Completed IS NULL
      GROUP BY CustomerId
     ) p
     ON p.CustomerId = c.Id;
```

This would normally be written without the subquery:

```
SELECT c.Id, COALESCE(SUM(p.Amount), 0) as DebitSum
FROM Customers c LEFT JOIN
     Purchases p
     ON p.CustomerId = c.Id;
WHERE p.Completed IS NULL
GROUP BY c.Id
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use `LEFT JOIN`:

```
SELECT Id, COALESCE(DebitSum,0) AS DebitSum
FROM Customers
LEFT JOIN (
            SELECT SUM(Amount) DebitSum, CustomerId
            FROM Purchases
            WHERE Completed IS NULL
            GROUP BY CustomerId
       ) p ON p.CustomerId = Id;
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
SELECT Id, DebitSum
FROM Customers
LEFT JOIN (
            SELECT SUM(Amount) DebitSum, CustomerId
            FROM Purchases
            WHERE Completed IS NULL
            GROUP BY CustomerId
       ) p ON p.CustomerId = Id;
```

Your doing a JOIN which means it has to exist in both tables/data sets.  Changing it to LEFT JOIN only requires it to be in the First table and not the one after the LEFT JOIN

Answer (score 1):

You can also use `subquery` only:

```
select id, (select coalesce(sum(p.Amount), 0) 
            from Purchases p 
            where p.CustomerId  = c.id and p.Completed IS NULL
            ) as DebitSum
from Customers c
group by id;
```

Comment: @LukaszSzozda. . . How could you think it will not work ?

Comment: Ok, agg function will handle it. It looks ok.

Answer (score 0):

`SELECT SUM(Amount) DebitSum, CustomerId`

there is no AS after the information? `select sum(amount) as debitsum, customerid`

Answer (score 0):

try this
SELECT c.Id, COALESCE(p.DebitSum, 0) as DebitSum
FROM Customers c LEFT JOIN Purchases p
 on  c.Id = p.CustomerId
where p.completed is null